# POWER BI: add information botton with text box

Tags: powerbi

I would like to know how it is possible to insert a button with the "i" of information and that when hovering over or clicking on it, a text box is displayed

Ty to all, sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Literally just insert an Information Button and set its tooltip property.

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It has worked. I'd like to bother you again, to find out why it is that when using the page navigation buttons, the button I'm "standing" on changes format (font type). Do you know why this happens and if it is possible to solve it?